# Are these version of Cauchy's Theorem (complex analysis) equivalent?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am looking through different complex analysis texts and comparing their statement and proofs of Cauchy's theorem. One version I found is:

[image]

A second version of Cauchy's Theorem is:
[image]

Now I was wondering if the corollary of the second version is in fact equivalent to the first version. The biggest difference I see is that the first version makes it clear that we need f to be analytic inside the closed curve whereas the second version doesn't say that. Is one of the four criterions equivalent to saying the interior of the curve is analytic?

Comment: No. It appears that you've cut off the rest of Theorem 3.3 which applies only to piecewise smooth paths. Corollary 3.1 is a specialization of Theorem 3.3 requiring that the path be closed.

Comment: Neither theorem 3.3 nor its corollary are forms of Cauchy's theorem, (which is why they are not called such). They are complex versions of the fundamental theorem of calculus. Note that in them you are integrating a derivative, while in Cauchy's theorem, you do not need to know that $f$ is the derivative of some other function (that is a consequence of Cauchy's theorem and integral formula, but you have to prove Cauchy's theorem to get that consequence).